# home icon in <ul> jquery menu header

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there a way to have a navbar in header followed by an icon ?

the only thing I can do is to have the icon within the third menu in navbar :

http://tof.canardpc.com/view/f0ad5385-09d9-4624-9324-d6cad4e0aad7.jpg

```
    <div data-role="navbar" data-theme="a">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#nav1">Nav 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#nav2">Nav 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#nav3">Nav 3</a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-theme="a" 
     class="ui-btn-right" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>

</div>
```

Could I do that programmatically ? Like the back button in every header ?

```
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnText = "previous";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all what you want to achieve i cnt understood but from the image you have provided it means that you want to make a home icon to the right of the nav bar...

To achieve you can use css to it and include it into the navbar...

Just add different classes in li's and provide them with different widths...

HTML:

```
<div data-role="haeder" data-theme="a">
        <ul data-role="navbar" data-theme="a">
            <li class="tap1"><a href="#nav1">Nav 1</a></li>
            <li class="tap2"><a href="#nav2">Nav 2</a></li>
            <li class="tap3"><a href="#nav3">Nav 3</a></li>
            <li class="tap4"><a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn-right" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>
```

CSS,

```
.tap1 { width:30% !important; }
.tap2 { width:30% !important; }
.tap3 { width:30% !important; }
.tap4 { width:10% !important; }
```

You can adjust the width percentage as your requirement...

Comment: Thanks. Id did try to add my icon into <li>, but ended with :
http://tof.canardpc.com/view/ff5ea64f-ee70-44d4-89bf-fddae27e8a7e.jpg
With or without the text, the navbar gets some ugly height

Comment: Remove 'Home' text from the link, make it a simple icon or If you want to add your own icon to it try this, [3rd party icon sets](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html)

Comment: Does not work with no text either, like I wrote above. the icon has a strange height...

Comment: Here's a good solution ; http://forum.jquery.com/topic/home-icon-in-ul-jquery-mobile-menu-header#14737000003450312